# Scalelite Nginx Not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

````
<returncode>FAILED</returncode>
<messageKey>unsupportedRequest</messageKey>
<message>This request is not supported.</message>
</response>``` 


 This is the response from the scalelite server when i enter the URL on browser. 

I am getting this message when i try to run 

```docker exec -i scalelite-api bundle exec rake db:setup```

ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
If you are sure you want to continue, run the same command with the environment variable:
DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
/srv/scalelite/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:63:in `check_protected_environments!'
/srv/scalelite/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/srv/scalelite/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:404:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/srv/scalelite/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
````

This is what i get when i enter the command
`docker exec -i scalelite-api bundle exec rake status`

domain.com  enabled  online         0      0              0       0

domain.com  enabled  online         0      0              0       0

Experts please help me with this. I am new to this

I am trying the balance the load between 2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

That's OK. You should check it with `https://your.scalelite.com/bigbluebutton/api/` not `https://your.scalelite.com`.

Comment: it's Not working